# Create dynamic Mountains based on Modifiers Issues with Heightfield Blending?

Tags: modifiers, displacement, height-map

I followed the tutorial **Blender tutorial: Create dynamic Mountains based on Modifiers:**

https://youtu.be/hUILySfQ3ic?si=EA-HQksLClQon6J_

I added 3 terrain controllers, 2 mountains and one for a riverbed.
I'm using heightmap alphas so I do not use the vertex weight modifier like shown in the tutorial.
(for the screenshot I disabled them)

[image: Blending]

[image]

Now my issues lies, when I try to overlap 2 mountains for instance I get a "pixel soup".

[image: Pixel Soup]

Any idea if that can be avoided?
I guess its due to how Blender handles the heightfield blending not having max values?

This is the displacement I used:
[image]

and its settings:
[image]

[image]

Any ideas appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "heightmap alphas", a height map is used for displacement and an alpha map is used for transparency. Anyway, without seeing any of your textures or how you have set up the "overlap" of two mountains (adding? multiplying? something else?) it is hard to tell what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hey, thanks for the response.

I updated the post with pictures of the displacement & settings.

I dont know how I would set the "overlap" "adding/multiply", since Its just using Displacement modifiers based on Geo that controls the heightmap manipluation on the terrain.

Since I come from 3ds Max/Maya and am no Blender expert I do not know were that would be set. I just followed the tutorial I linked and its setup.

Comment: I have no time to watch a 20 minute tutorial completely to find out where they are doing this, sorry. I do not know if they are stacking height maps onto each other, but if so you cannot leave the _Direction_ set to _Normal_, because the when the first modifier displaces something, the normals are no longer pointing upwards but e.g. to the sides on a slope, so the next height map will be displaced in this direction. You should switch the _Direction_ to _Z_ instead. Of course this only works well with a plane that is supposed to be only displaced upwards.

Comment: Hey Gordon, no problem.
That kinda fixed it setting it from "Normal" direction to "Z" instead.
I did not even notice, that I had it set to "normal direction", but it makes sense why it would then push those verts out.

Vielen Dank!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I have no time to write a proper answer with some screenshots. Because you know, in case you maybe have a second displacement modifier with a tiny cloud texture to create finer detail like a kind of grainy surface it would probably not matter much to use _Normal_, however what is still important then is the order of modifiers. If you would first make the fine detail and then displace the large scale mountain based on those normals, the result will be terrible :D

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.
Luckily I just wanna use this as a rough non-destructive blockout of terrain, to then run through an erosion pass in WM/Gaea. I just needed to have a quick iterative workflow.

Ideally something like Houdini probably would be even more elegant, or geo nodes in Blender.

Again thanks for helping me out.